# Overriding of Dictionary<K,V>.KeyCollection

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, overriding

I am trying to inherit from `Dictionary<K,V>`, but my problem is, that when the Dictionary.Keys are being queried, I want to override them. (that is, the KeyCollection) of the dictionary.

How can that be solved?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Encapsulate `Dictionary<K,V>`

and

- Implement `IDictionary<K,V>`.

---

or

```
public new YourType Keys
{
    get
    {
        return yourVersion;
    }
}
```

Note:

- `IDictionary<K,V>.Keys` has type `ICollection<Key>`
- `Dictionary<K,V>.Keys` has type `Dictionary<K, V>.KeyCollection` but it's marked as `sealed` so you will not be able to inherit it, so option 1 seems to be more realistic.

Comment: I would **definitely** recommend your first option (encapsulate `Dictionary<K,V>` and implement `IDictionary<K,V>`) otherwise when you cast your dictionary to `IDictionary<K, V>` you will find that your `Keys` property is ignored because of the use of the `new` keyword.